# solution of the Pythagorean triple (a,b,21025)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that most intelligent people on this site will find this elementary question very simple (I hope you'll forgive me, I'm not yet familiar enough with mathematics):

> What is the solution of the Pythagorean triple $(a,b,21025)$,$a^2+b^2=21025^2$ such that
>   it is primitive?

Comment: I think there are several considering $$24^2+143^2=21025$$$$17^2+144^2=21025$$

Comment: This uses $$21025=(5^2+2^2)(2^2+5^2)(1^2+2^2)(2^2+1^2)$$ and Braghmagupta's Identity.

Comment: Do we want to find $a + b = 21025$ or $a^2 + b^2 = 21025^2$ though?

Comment: With $a,b,21025$ coprime we seem to have $(4896,20447,21025)$ and $(6864,19873,21025)$.

Comment: @kennytm $21025=(145)^2$. Maybe there is a mistake in the question.